# Ofnuts GIMP Tools on 2.10.6

Tags: text, path, gimp

Trying to curve some text on an image using the Text Along Path method, but the text keeps distorting. Found these tools http://gimp-path-tools.sourceforge.net/tools.shtml#text-along-path and installed the text-along-path tool. However, the plug-in does not appear to be working. Does anyone know if these tools are compatible with GIMP 2.10.6?

Comment: Gimp 2.10.* requires python 2 for gimp-path-tools to work, there is a good chance that your OS only has python3, the best solution I found was to install a flatpak version of Gimp that comes with its own Python support https://www.gimp.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

They are, and as far as I can tell the plugin works.  But `text-along-path` has been replaced by `ofn-text-along-path` (that comes with its own documentation).

[image]

Can you amend your question to explain what you mean by "*the plug-in does not appear to be working*"? Doesn't appear in menus (it is in the right click menu of paths in the Paths list (`Tools>Text along path` at the bottom)? No dialog appears? The plugin crashes when running?

You can get help [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-ofn-text-along-path).